Connecting ESP32 to Python interface through serial connection
I'm having trouble connecting my ESP32 to my python interface using serial connection.
The ESP32 is on a system reading sensors values via Arduino. I'm using a Python interface to display those readings and also show them as graphs. The problem is, when I connect the ESP32 to the interface I get this log error: utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: invalid continuation byte but when I tried with another ESP32 that wasn't linked to the sensor system but had an Arduino code that was generating the values in the needed intervals, it worked perfectly.
Does anyone know how to solve this? I can share my Arduino and Python code if needed.
Also before that I had trouble with the pyserial library, had to uninstall and install it for it to work.
Arduino:
//--------------------------------------------- Librairies ------------------------------------------------------------------//
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADS1X15.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define SENSOR_PIN  2
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
Adafruit_ADS1115 ads; // Adresse I2C de l'ADS1115
File dataFile;
//-------------------------------- Variables pour minuteur d'acquisition ----------------------------------------------------//
// Minuteur, mieux qu'un delay car un delay bloque le code et lui dit de ne rien faire pendant le temps bloqué, pas le cas avec un minuteur
unsigned long Clck_Aqc = millis();
unsigned long delai_ACQ = 1000;

unsigned long Clck_uSD = millis();
unsigned long delai_uSD = 1000 * 5;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//--------------------------------------------- Variables pour ADC ----------------------------------------------------------//
uint32_t adc0_DO = 0;
uint32_t adc1 = 0;
uint32_t adc2_temp =0;
float DO_value = 0;
float pH_value = 0;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//--------------------------------------------- Variabless DS18B20 ----------------------------------------------------------//
float Temperature = 0;
OneWire oneWire(SENSOR_PIN);
DallasTemperature DS18B20(&oneWire);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//--------------------------------------------- Variables pour carte uSD ----------------------------------------------------//
String labelsDonneesSD = "Date,DO,PH,Temperature \r\n";
String donneesSD = "";
int SD_CS = 5;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//---------------------------------------------- Variables pour l'horloge ---------------------------------------------------//
RTC_DS3231 rtc; //module RTC
String Date;
String heure;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  DS18B20.begin();    // initialize the DS18B20 sensor
  Wire.begin();
  Start_ADC();
  Start_uSD();
  initRTC();
}
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    
void loop() {
  if (millis() - Clck_Aqc >= delai_ACQ) {
    Clck_Aqc = millis();
    Lire_ADC();
    AfficheValeurs();                          
  }
    if (millis() - Clck_uSD >= delai_uSD) {
    Clck_uSD = millis();
    // Ajout des données au fichier CSV
    Enregistrement_SD();                             
  } //if millis
} //void loop

Void AfficheValeurs(){
 // Affiche dans le moniteur série
  Serial.print("DO : ");
  Serial.print(DO_value);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print("pH : ");
  Serial.print(pH_value);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print("Temperature : ");
  Serial.print(Temperature);
  Serial.print("C");
  Serial.print("\n");
} // void AfficheValeurs

Python:
from settings import *
from main_menu import MainMenu
from graphs import Graph4H, Graph24H
from log_menu import LogMenu

#TODO:
"""
Add a settings menu for:
 - autosaving capacity (switch)
 - Changing the port (combobox)
 - changing the baudrate (combobox)
"""


class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("900x600+100+50")
        self.title("Bioreacteur")

        self.small_size_font = ctk.CTkFont(size=14)
        self.medium_size_font = ctk.CTkFont(size=18)
        self.large_size_font = ctk.CTkFont(size=24)
        self.huge_size_font = ctk.CTkFont(size=36)

        self.has_exited = False
        self.serial_port = None 
        self.serial_thread = None

        self.last_opened_tab = None
                
        self.port = ctk.StringVar(value="COM4")
        self.baudrate = ctk.IntVar(value=9600)
        
        self.do = ctk.DoubleVar()
        self.ph = ctk.DoubleVar()
        self.temp = ctk.DoubleVar()
        
        self.do.trace_add("write", lambda *args: self.menu_frame.do_label.configure(text=f"DO : {self.do.get()}"))
        self.ph.trace_add("write", lambda *args: self.menu_frame.ph_label.configure(text=f"pH : {self.ph.get()}"))
        self.temp.trace_add("write", lambda *args: self.menu_frame.temperature_label.configure(text=f"Temperature : {self.temp.get()}"))

        self.create_widgets()
        
        # csv_filename = f"data/d-{datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}.csv" if seperated method is wanted
        self.day_data = {}
        if self.file_check(CSV_FILENAME):
            self.day_data = self.load_data("4H")
            
        log_filename = f"logs/log-{datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}.json"
        self.logs = []
        if self.file_check(log_filename):
            logs = self.load_logs(log_filename)
            if logs is None:
                return 
            
            for log in logs:
                self.log_errors(log)

    def file_check(self, filename: str):
        """
        Checks if a file exists and creates it if not.

        Args:
            filename (str): Path to the file.
        """
        if not (return_val := os.path.exists(filename)):
            # Create the file with write mode ('w') and newline='' for proper handling
            with open(filename, 'x', newline='') as f:
                if filename.endswith('.csv'):
                    writer = csv.writer(f)
                    writer.writerow(["Day","Timestamp", "DO", "pH", "Temperature"])
        
        return return_val

    def create_widgets(self):
        def open_tab(frame: ctk.CTkFrame, title: str):
            self.title(title)
            frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.9)
            frame.extra()
            if self.last_opened_tab is not None: frame.lift(self.last_opened_tab)
            self.last_opened_tab = frame

        # Tab Frames
        self.menu_frame = MainMenu(master=self)
        self.graph_4h_frame = Graph4H(master=self)
        self.graph_24h_frame = Graph24H(master=self)
        self.log_errors_frame = LogMenu(master=self)

        # Tab switching Buttons
        self.menu_btn = ctk.CTkButton(
            master=self, 
            text="Menu", 
            corner_radius=0, 
            fg_color=BUTTON_FG_COLOR,
            text_color=BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR,
            command=lambda: open_tab(self.menu_frame, "Bioreacteur: Menu")
        )
        self.graph_4h_btn = ctk.CTkButton(
            master=self, 
            text="Graph 4h", 
            corner_radius=0, 
            fg_color=BUTTON_FG_COLOR,
            text_color=BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR,
            command=lambda: open_tab(self.graph_4h_frame, "Bioreacteur: Graph des 4 dernières heures")
        )
        self.graph_24h_btn = ctk.CTkButton(
            master=self, 
            text="Graph 24h", 
            corner_radius=0, 
            fg_color=BUTTON_FG_COLOR,
            text_color=BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR,
            command=lambda: open_tab(self.graph_24h_frame, "Bioreacteur: Graph des 24 dernières heures")
        )
        self.log_errors_btn = ctk.CTkButton(
            master=self, 
            text="Log Errors", 
            corner_radius=0, 
            fg_color=BUTTON_FG_COLOR,
            text_color=BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR,
            command=lambda: open_tab(self.log_errors_frame, "Bioreacteur: Log Erreurs")
        )

        self.menu_btn.place(relx=0, rely=1, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.1, anchor="sw")
        self.graph_4h_btn.place(relx=0.25, rely=1, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.1, anchor="sw")
        self.graph_24h_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=1, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.1, anchor="sw")
        self.log_errors_btn.place(relx=0.75, rely=1, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.1, anchor="sw")
        
        open_tab(self.menu_frame, "Bioreacteur: Menu")

    def log_errors(self, error_message: Union[Exception, str], custom_error_message: Optional[str] = "Erreur lors de l'analyse des données :"):
        print(error_message)
        error_message = error_message if isinstance(error_message, str) else f"({datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')}): {custom_error_message}\n{str(error_message)}\n"
        self.menu_frame.log_error_text.insert(ctk.END, error_message)
        self.log_errors_frame.text.insert(ctk.END, error_message)
        self.logs.append(error_message)

    def connect(self, timeout: int = 1):
        self.toggle_enregistrement_auto()
    
        # Cette fonction est appelée lors du clic sur le bouton "Se connecter"
        print(self.port.get(), self.baudrate.get())
        # Essaye de se connecter à la carte
        try:
            self.serial_port = serial.Serial(port=self.port.get(), baudrate=self.baudrate.get(), timeout=timeout)  # Ouverture du port série
            if not self.serial_port.is_open:
                self.serial_port.open()
            # Si la connexion est réussie, mettre à jour l'interface utilisateur
            self.menu_frame.connect_btn.configure(text="Connecté", state=DISABLED)
            # Lance la récupération des données
            self.start_reading_serial()
        except Exception as e:
            # En cas d'échec de la connexion, afficher un message d'erreur dans le log
            self.log_errors(e)

    def start_reading_serial(self):
        # Cette fonction démarre le thread de lecture des données série
        self.serial_thread = thread.Thread(target=self.read_serial)
        self.serial_thread.daemon = True  # Le thread se terminera lorsque le programme principal se terminera
        self.serial_thread.start()

    def enregistrer_csv(self):
        # Récupére les valeurs actuelles des labels DO, pH et Température
        self.do_value = self.do.get()
        self.ph_value = self.ph.get()
        self.temperature = self.temp.get()

        if (self.do_value, self.ph_value, self.temperature) == (0, 0, 0):
            return

        # Obtenir la date et l'heure actuelles
        current_day, current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M:%S").split(", ")

        for category, data in (("Timestamp", current_time), ("DO", self.do_value), ("pH", self.ph_value), ("Temperature", self.temperature)):
            self.day_data[current_day][category].append(data)

        # Écrire les données dans un fichier CSV
        with open(f"data/data.csv", mode="a", newline="") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            # Écrire les en-têtes de colonnes s'il s'agit d'un nouveau fichier
            writer.writerow([current_day, current_time, self.do_value, self.ph_value, self.temperature])

    def load_data(self, _type: Literal["4H", "24H"]) -> dict[str, dict[str, list[int]]]:
        output_dict = {}
                
        with open(CSV_FILENAME, mode="r") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            
            data = list(reader)
            if len(data) == 0:
                return output_dict
            
            headers = data[0]  # Get the headers from the first row

            # Process each data row
            if _type == "4H":
                date_str = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
                
                output_dict[date_str] = {header: [] for header in headers[1:]}
                day_data = output_dict[date_str]
                
                for row in data[1:]:
                    if row[0] != date_str:
                        continue                        
                        
                    for i, value in enumerate(row):
                        if i == 0:
                            continue
                        
                        day_data[headers[i]].append(value)
                    
            else:
                previous_date = data[1][0] #Get the first date of the data
                for row_index in range(len(data)):
                    if row_index == 0:
                        continue
                    
                    row = data[row_index]  #Get the current row

                    date_str = row[0] #Get the date at position 0 of the row
                    
                    if date_str != previous_date: #Check if the new date is different from the last
                        previous_date = date_str #If the case then sum up all the values of the day before reseting them

                        for header, values in day_data.items():
                            if header == "Timestamp":
                                continue

                            day_data[header] = round(sum(values) / len(values), 2)  # Calculer la moyenne des valeurs
                    
                    if date_str not in output_dict.keys():
                        output_dict[date_str] = {header: [] for header in headers[1:]}
                        
                    day_data = output_dict[date_str]
                                        
                    for i, value in enumerate(row):
                        if i == 0:
                            continue
                        
                        day_data[headers[i]].append(float(value) if len(value) <= 5 else value)
                
                for header, values in day_data.items():
                    if header == "Timestamp":
                        continue

                    day_data[header] = round(sum(values) / len(values), 2)  # Calculer la moyenne des valeurs
            
        return output_dict

    def load_logs(self, filename: str) -> list[str]:                
        try:
            with open(filename, "r") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
            return data
        except (json.JSONDecodeError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
            # Handle the empty file case or other exceptions
            self.log_errors(error_message=e, custom_error_message="Loading Error: Could not load logs from file:")
            return []
            
        
    def save_logs(self, filename: str, data: list[str]):                
        try:
            with open(filename, "w") as f:
                json.dump(data, f)
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle the empty file case or other exceptions
            self.log_errors(e)                
        

    def read_serial(self):
        # Cette fonction lit les données série et les affiche dans l'interface graphique
        while True:
            try:
                # Lire les données série
                print(self.serial_port.readline())
                data = self.serial_port.readline().decode("utf-8").strip()
                if data == "":
                    continue
                # Analyser les données
                self.analyze_data(data)
            except Exception as e:
                # Afficher l'erreur dans l'interface graphique
                self.log_errors(e)
                print(e)
                
                # Arrêter le thread de lecture des données série
                # if self.serial_thread: self.serial_thread.join()
                self.has_exited = True

                # Quitter le programme
                exit(1)

    def analyze_data(self, data: str):
        # Cette fonction analyse les données série et met à jour les labels DO, pH et Température
        try:
            if data == "":
                return
            
            # Séparer les données en trois parties : DO, pH et Température
            do, ph, temperature = data.split(",")
            do = do.split(":")[1]
            ph = ph.split(":")[1]
            temperature = temperature.split(":")[1]
            temperature = temperature[:-2]
            
            # Convertir les données en nombres
            do = round(float(do), 2)
            ph = round(float(ph), 2)
            temperature = round(float(temperature), 2)

            # Mettre à jour les labels DO, pH et Température
            self.do.set(do)
            self.ph.set(ph)
            self.temp.set(temperature)
        except Exception as e:
            # Afficher l'erreur dans l'interface graphique
            self.log_errors(e)

    def toggle_enregistrement_manuel(self):
        self.enregistrement_auto_active = False
        self.menu_frame.save_btn.configure(state="normal")
        
    def toggle_enregistrement_auto(self):
            self.enregistrement_auto_active = True
            self.menu_frame.save_btn.configure(state="disabled")  # Désactiver le bouton pour éviter d'être pressé à nouveau
            self.start_auto_enregistrement()
    
    def start_auto_enregistrement(self):
        if self.enregistrement_auto_active or not self.has_exited:
            self.enregistrer_csv()
            self.after(1000, self.start_auto_enregistrement)  # Appeler cette méthode toutes les 1000 millisecondes (1 seconde)

    def destroy(self):
        # if self.serial_thread is not None: self.serial_thread.join(99)
        # if self.serial_port is not None: self.serial_port.close()
        self.has_exited = True

        try:
            log_filename = f"logs/log-{datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}.json"
            if self.file_check(log_filename): self.save_logs(log_filename, self.logs)
        except Exception as e:
            self.log_errors(e)
   
        # print(self.csv_load_data(_type="4h"))

        super().destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


Possibly an incorrect baud rate setting.  How could we possibly do more than make wild guesses, without actually seeing either side of the code?

Edit the code into the question, so that it's actually readable.  But the problem may be those non-ASCII characters you're sending - é and °, for example.  I have no idea how the Arduino end will encode those, but I wouldn't expect it to be UTF-8, which is how the Python end is trying to decode them.

I just added it, also I tried without the é and ° but it changes nothing

Arduino framework does not encode data in UTF-8, whatever received from ESP32, it should be decoded with decode('ascii') instead of decode('utf-8').

Found the solution to the problem! It was a capacitor of 10µF on the EN/RESET pin of the ESP32 that was blocking the data from being received by the python interface, taking it off has solved the problem. Thank for the help nonetheless.
